# fetching records from MongoDB based on no of digits in integer value

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to fetch records from my mongoDB based on the number of digits presented in the integer field(it is nested attribute). Since mongoDB do not have function to calculate number of digit presented in an integer field I am using below query to suit my purpose but I am getting an error.

```
db.collection.find({"Data.Integer_field": {$exists: true}, $where: function(){return toString("Data.Integer_field").length: {$gt:12}; } }).limit(2);
```

Comment: Why aren't you just doing a numerical comparison like `Data.Integer_field: {$gte: 1000}` for the 4 digit case, for example?

Comment: Cause it will not include the case where  the digits are 00100 as not rounding the zeros from data

Comment: So `Integer_field` is a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following solution:

```
db.collection.find({
    "Data.Integer_field" : {"$type" : 16}
}).forEach(function(doc){
    if(doc.Data.Integer_field.toString().length > 12) {
        print(doc);
    }
});
```

$type is to check the data type (16 is 32-bit integer) Check [Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/)

You can use either $type or $exists, whatever is feasible to you.

And in this example I am printing the results, but you work it out your way. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Awesome! No problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script.

```
db.collection.find( {
    "Data.Integer_field":{$exists: true}, 
    $where: function() { return ((new String(this.Data.Integer_field)).length > 12 ) ; } 
 } ).limit(2);
```